# How to extract New Mexico state from USA boundaries package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a Tmap with two points but I am having some issues.

```
`library(tmap) 
library(maps)
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)
#Open soil pit location data
data<-read.csv("SoilPit_Locations___.csv")
#Converting locations to an sf object
points<-st_as_sf(data,coords=c("Longitude","Latitude"),crs=4326)
#Set up map mode as view for an interactive map
tmap_mode("plot")
#Set up style as natural to view topography
tmap_style("natural")
#Map us borders and add points for locations as dots
#tm_shape(us) + tm_borders("black", lwd = .5) + 
m=tm_shape(points)+tm_dots() 
m
tmap_save(m, "my_mapp.png")`
```

The issue I am having is that when I try run my code the two points are on the corners of the map, I would like to plot them on the New Mexico state map so they can look nicer.

I have tried extracting the NM state boundary from the world map but I have been unsuccessful.

Comment: What did you do to try and extract the NM state boundary? How did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
library(USAboundariesData)
```

then you get `states_contemporary_lores` (amongst other things) which are the USA state boundaries, so you can subset NM like this:

```
nm = states_contemporary_lores[
    states_contemporary_lores$state_abbr=="NM",
    ]
```

and then `nm` is an `sf` object which is just New Mexico. You can map this in `tmap` using `tm_shape(nm) + tm_borders()` and then adding whatever other layers you have.